# Print all matches of a regular expression from the command line?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

What's the simplest way to print all matches (either one line per match or one line per line of input) to a regular expression on a unix command line? Note that there may be 0 or more than 1 match per line of input.

I assume there must be some way to do this with sed, awk, grep, and/or perl, and I'm hoping for a simple command line solution so it will show up in my bash history when needed in the future.

EDIT: To clarify, I do not want to print all matching lines, only the matches to the regular expression. For example, a line might have 1000 characters, but there are only two 10-character matches to the regular expression. I'm only interested in those two 10-character matches.

Comment: to a regex? I presume you mean of a regex

Comment: Sorry, could you expand a bit on what you want?  On the surface, this just sounds like a bare-bones 'grep', but I know that can't be all there is to it.  :)

Comment: Suppose the input is "fod,food,fad\nbar\nfoooood\n" and the regular expression is "fo*d". Then the output should be "fod\nfood\nfoooood\n", or "fodfood\n\nfoooood\n".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you only use non-capturing parentheses,

```
perl -wnE'say /yourregex/g'
```

or

```
perl -wnE'say for /yourregex/g'
```

Sample use:

```
$ echo -ne 'fod,food,fad\nbar\nfooooood\n' | perl -wnE'say for /fo*d/g'
fod
food
fooooood
$ echo -ne 'fod,food,fad\nbar\nfooooood\n' | perl -wnE'say /fo*d/g'
fodfood

fooooood
```

Comment: Just noticed that `grep -o 'fo*d' input.txt` seems to work as well. Color can be removed with `--color=never` if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Unless I misunderstand your question, the following will do the trick

```
grep -o 'fo.*d' input.txt
```

For more details see:

- [GNU grep (most platforms)](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
- [Solaris grep](http://manpages.unixforum.co.uk/man-pages/unix/solaris-10-11_06/1/grep-man-page.html)
- [AIX grep](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/grep.htm)
- [HP-UX grep](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/grep.1.html)

Comment: It shouldn't print the whole matching line.

Comment: [`ack -o`](http://betterthangrep.com) and GNU `grep -o` will show only the matched part. Combine the latter with `-P` for Perl-style regex.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the comment, and assuming you're passed the input from a pipe or otherwise on `STDIN`:

```
perl -e 'my $re=shift;$re=~qr{$re};while(<STDIN>){if(/($re)/g){print"$1\n"}while(m/\G.*?($re)/g){print"$1\n"}}'
```

Usage:

```
cat SOME_TEXT_FILE | perl -e 'my $re=shift;$re=~qr{$re};while(<STDIN>){if(/($re)/g){print"$1\n"}while(m/\G.*?($re)/g){print"$1\n"}}' 'YOUR_REGEX'
```

or I would just stuff that whole mess into a bash function...

```
bggrep ()
{
    if [ "x$1" != "x" ]; then
        perl -e 'my $re=shift;$re=~qr{$re};while(<STDIN>){if(/($re)/g){print"$1\n"}while(m/\G.*?($re)/g){print"$1\n"}}' $1;
    else
        echo "Usage: bggrep <regex>";
    fi
}
```

Usage is the same, just cleaner-looking:

```
cat SOME_TEXT_FILE | bggrep 'YOUR_REGEX'
```

(or just type the command itself and enter the text to match line-by-line, but that didn't seem a likely use case :).

Example (from your comment):

```
bash$ cat garbage
fod,food,fad
bar
fooooooood
bash$ cat garbage | perl -e 'my $re=shift;$re=~qr{$re};while(<STDIN>){if(/($re)/g){print"$1\n"}while(m/\G.*?($re)/g){print"$1\n"}}' 'fo*d'
fod
food
fooooooood
```

or...

```
bash$ cat garbage | bggrep 'fo*d'
fod
food
fooooooood
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MSmart::Comments -ne '@a=m/(...)/g;print;' -e '### @a'
```